# Refactor jQuery AJAX call for partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.net MVC 5 application, I have lots of call to different partial views. To load/refresh those view, I am using jQuery AJAX.

However I ended up having lot of call to jquery which seems ugly and redundant. I am thinking there must be a better way to do this.

Here is my script in my `index.cshtml` where I am calling partial views.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // load today's level
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_TodayLevel")',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'html',
            //traditional: true,
        }).success(function(e) {
            $('#today-level').html(e);
        });

        // .... truncated to save space. But you get the idea, I have lots of this

        // load host level
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_HostLevel")',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'html',
            //traditional: true,
        }).success(function (e) {
            $('#host-level').html(e);
        });
    });
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you gave, you are essentially requesting an HTML page and then updating a portion of the page with the returned HTML.

If this is the case, then you can simply use jQuery's `.load()` method:  https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You may simply consider to use below code to achieve what you want

```
@{Html.renderaction("_TodayLevel","Controller");}
```

If you does not have any controller action for this two views you may also consider to use

```
@{Html.renderPartial("_yourViews");}
```

Comment: I was using `RenderAction` but my action is `async` and so far `RenderAction` does not support asynchronous controller. I keep getting error if I use `RenderAction` with it. It works though for `sync` action.